# Find the error in the proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Theorem:** Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Let $a=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{m>n}x_m$. We know that this limit is well-defined since the sequence $(\sup_{m>n}x_m)_{n \geq 1}$ is monotone non-increasing and bounded. We claim that there exists a subsequence of $(x_{n_i})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{n_i} \rightarrow a$.

Indeed, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n>n_0 \Rightarrow |a-\sup_{m>n}x_m|<\varepsilon/2.$$

From the supremum definition, we obtain $n_i >n$ such that
$$|\sup_{m>n}x_m-x_{n_i}|<\varepsilon/2.$$

Therefore, for $n>n_0$ fixed we obtain $n_i>n$ such that
\begin{align}
|a-x_{n_i}|\leq& |a-\sup_{m>n}x_m|+|\sup_{m>n}x_m-x_{n_i}|\\
<&\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2= \varepsilon.
\end{align}

It seems that the sequence thus constructed does not satisfies $n_1<n_2<\cdots$.

Could some one give me an explicit counterexample for this?

Comment: If $(x_n)$ is a constant sequence then all the stated inequalities hold when $n_i=1 \forall i$ But $(x_1,x_1,x_1,...)$ is not a subseqeunce of $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your proof. Modifying it slightly gives something more convincing :

Set $S_n=\sup_{m\geq n}x_m$. You have that $S_n\to a$ whenever $n\to \infty $.

- Take $n_1$ s.t. $|S_{n_1}-a|<1$.
- Take $n_2>n_1$ s.t. $|S_{n_2}-a|<\frac{1}{2}$

$\vdots$

- Take $n_{k}>n_{k-1}$ s.t. $|S_{n_k}-a|<\frac{1}{k}$

$\vdots$

Then $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $a$.